# Hosting two SSL sites (different host name) on same server with different certificates and without ports (i.e. 443)

Tags: sharepoint, ssl-certificate, iis-6, alternate-access-mappings

We have a SharePoint site https://example.com hosted on port 443.

There is another site https://anotherexample.com that should be hosted on same server and without port (i.e. 443).

Both the certificates are issued to different host names (i.e. not wildcard certificate).

How can I achieve above scenario?

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: I'm working on IIS 8.

Comment: What do you mean by without ports?

Comment: the url should be like https://anotherexample.com

Comment: Is it possible for you to change IIS version to 8?

Comment: I have edited the post, actually i'm working on IIS 8.
How can I achieve above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to achieve this on IIS 8 is to use Server Name Indication. It allows the server to host multiple certificates for multiple sites under a single IP address.

For more detailed instructions, please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability).